# SQL Query - in how many countries we have users and in how many countries we don't have users

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Need a SQL query that will answer this question.

Please tell us in how many countries we have users and in how many countries we don't have users. This should be presented in a table, in a single row and two columns (one with the number of countries in which we have users and one with the number of countries where we don't have users).

We have two tables: AllCountriesInTheWorld and AllUsers.

Table AllCountriesInTheWorld

| country_id | country_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | USA |
| 2 | France |
| 3 | Italy |
| 4 | Portugal |
| 5 | Spain |
| 6 | Canada |
| 7 | UK |
| 8 | China |
| 9 | Japan |
| 10 | Germany |

Table AllUsers

| user_id | user_name | country_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | John | 4 |
| b2 | Jane | 6 |
| c3 | Tony | 6 |
| d4 | Dan | 9 |
| e5 | Dave | 1 |

Thanks a lot in advance guys!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you LEFT JOIN the 2 tables on their common key,
then you can get all countries with or without users.

```
select *
from AllCountriesInTheWorld ctry
left join AllUsers usr
  on usr.country_id = ctry.country_id
```

| country_id | country_name | user_id | user_name | country_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | e5 | Dave | 1 |
| 2 | France | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | Italy | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 4 | Portugal | a1 | John | 4 |
| 5 | Spain | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 6 | Canada | b2 | Jane | 6 |
| 6 | Canada | c3 | Tony | 6 |
| 7 | UK | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 8 | China | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 9 | Japan | d4 | Dan | 9 |
| 10 | Germany | *null* | *null* | *null* |

If you then GROUP BY the countries then you can COUNT how many USER_ID each country has.

```
count(usr.user_id) as total_users
```

| country_id | total_users |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 0 |

Then just wrap that in a CTE or sub-query and use conditional aggregation on the total users.

```
;with CTE_COUNTRIES as (
   ... 
)
select 
  sum(case when total_users > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as countries_with_users
, sum(case when total_users = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as countries_without_users
from CTE_COUNTRIES
```

| countries_with_users | countries_without_users |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 6 |